# Trouble running app engine python sdk

Tags: python, google-app-engine, installation, ubuntu-11.10

I have downloaded google_appengine_1.7.3.zip
and followed the guidelines given and made the necessary changes to .bashrc
[as given here](http://www.johnogrady.com/blog/2012/09/01/setup-google-app-engine-on-ubuntu/).
Here are my [main.py](http://www.pastebin.com/BJTU3ezB) and [app.yaml](http://www.pastebin.com/WYJ8Crca) which lie in a folder named udacity.

On entering the following in my terminal,

```
python google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --use_sqlite --port=1234 genprojects/udacity/
```

I get the [following message](http://www.pastebin.com/LgPDGKmn)
I am using Ubuntu 11.10.
Please help!

Comment: Some quick [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=No+address+associated+with+hostname) points to this being a problem with DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no ip that corresponed to localhost in my file /etc/hosts. So it failed to get the IP from domain name - localhost
Add the following line to the file /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.2   localhost
```

[reference](http://www.linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_hosts.htm)